# How can I analyse multiple choice questions in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, survey

I have a CSV from an online survey including numerical, single choice and multiple choice questions. The multiple choice questions are represented like this:

```
┌─────┬─────┬────┬─────┐
│  A  │  B  │ C  │  D  │
├─────┼─────┼────┼─────┤
│ "Y" │ NA  │ NA │ NA  │
│ NA  │ "Y" │ NA │ "Y" │
│ NA  │ NA  │ NA │ NA  │
│ "Y" │ "Y" │ NA │ NA  │
└─────┴─────┴────┴─────┘
```

So an answer is either the character "Y" or null.

Now my question is if there is a solution which lets me easily make a histogram or something similar to visualize the frequency of each answer and use it in statistical testing in R.

Sorry if this is trivial but I don't have the experience and couldn't dig something up yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your csv is read in as a dataframe, df then:

```
df2 <- !is.na(df)
nrows <- nrow(df2)
yes <- apply(df2, 2, sum)
percentyes <- 100 * yes / nrows
percentno = 100 - percentyes
barplot(percentyes)
```

Comment: I understand the logic in this. However it doesn't work, as `colSums()` expects numerical values and I only have the character "Y". I will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Right.  Sorry.  Updated solution posted.  The "Y"s are converted to TRUE and summed.  There may be a simpler way but this one works.